# Forcing a trailing slash before URL query

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I know this is a subject that comes up a lot, so I'll just make sure everyone knows: I have read and tried many of the rewrite suggestions on here already, with no luck.

---

I have a WordPress install (nginx server, virtual machine w/ apache) that's running just fine, but there's an issue with directories + queries in the URL. If the directory does not have a trailing slash before the query, it does not resolve (bounces back to blog index).

Example:

**www.example.com/blog/?=generic_query** works just fine.

**www.example.com/blog?=generic_query** does not.

Unfortunately, the theme I've installed (X-Theme) has some admin menus that point to pages without the trailing slash on the directory before the query.

I have tried to rewrite the conditions within htaccess but I just haven't had any success. I've read others saying that PHP usually doesn't care at all about this, so the fact that this is making a fuss with this strange nginx install makes me wonder if it's a server issue.

Does anyone have any suggestions for this very specific issue? It'd be much appreciated if so!

Thank you

--

Edit: Putting my root htaccess file here.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Please explain what you actually mean by "(nginx server, virtual machine w/ apache)"... Now what is it, nginx _or_ apache?

Comment: We can just call it apache, but set up on a virtual machine by some guy who is only familiar with nginx servers :|

Answer (score 2):

Put this in `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,7}\s/(.*?)([^\/])\?(.*)\sHTTP.*$
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$    /%1%2/?%3   [L]
```

Second lime will check if the request has no `/` before `?` .

Third line will add it to request internally .

**UPDATE :**

Save your previous rules and put this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /blog(/)?\?(.*)\sHTTP.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: I believe you're working the correct angle, but my public facing pages get messed up when I add it to my htaccess and I can't access the admin page

Comment: I edited the original post to include my htaccess file - I tried placing your condition and rule lines above, and then below the rest of the stuff there, but each time it made problems with the install.

Comment: I dunno what you mean - /blog/ is the directory in which wordpress is installed, so I suppose it's redundant to specify that.

Comment: i meant any request has this /bolg/?whatever right?

Comment: I suppose so, yes - WordPress specifies URL.com/blog/ as the root of the install, that's where all the files are

Comment: @Joel see the Update

Comment: Same result :'( - I really appreciate you working with it though, it's a tricky issue. I don't know if it makes a difference, but the issue is occurring from within the admin menu - this is the URL that's not working: www.URL.io/blog?cs-launch=1&cs_route=content  -- it works fine when you put the slash before the query. I've searched for more htaccess files in child directories, but coming up with nothing...maybe I should double check though.